# Detect the first run of code

Tags: php

I am trying to make a web application which I want to run in different server or within the same server with different urls. I want to detect the first run of the program and want to send some notification to a specific email address about the run.

How can I track the first run of the program in any server when someone copies or clones the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do an entry in some database table on the first run. And then check if there is some entry.

Or you could create a file on first run and then check if file exists.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent running of the further code after detecting the first run?

Comment: Yes, there is.  If (!file_exists ($file)){ file_put_contents ($file, $content);  die('This was the first run of script');} The next time the if clause will be FALSE.